# Best way to manage EventListener on a large scale application in actionscript and Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, garbage-collection, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a big mobile application in flex 4.5, and using "big" I mean big..

1. 50+ views
2. 50+ custom components
3. 10+ custom events
4. 50+ custom classes (not UIComponents)
5. Lot of skins, etc...

I never removed an EventListener, and now I'm looking at the flash profiler and I there are a lot of memory leaks..
I actually thought that using `navigator.pushView` or `navigator.popView()` or `navigator.popToFirstView()` will remove any reference of all the object/variable in the view itself and garbaged collected..

I'm trying to fix my code but I have a lot of problems understanding how to works with event listeners...

I think that it will be easier if I use some examples instead of describing every possible case...

**Example 1:**

```
private function XXX():void
{
  var x:ClassA = new ClassA();
  x.addEventListener(CustomEvent.GETA, doSomething);
  x.addEventListener(CustomEvent2.TESTB, doSomethingElse);
}
private function doSomething(e:CustomEvent):void{}
private function doSomethingElse(e:CustomEvent2):void{}
```

Do I need to remove both eventListener after one is fired?
if yes, do I need to remove both event listener both in doSomething and in doSomethingElse?

Is it better to use a weakReference in the addeventlistener?
`x.addEventListener(CustomEvent.GETA, doSomething, false, 0, true);`

**Example 2:**

`tile` is a TileGroup, but it could be everything...

```
protected function activate(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
{               
tile.removeAllElements();
for (var i:int = 1 ; i < functionCount.length ; i++)
{           
var t:ImageButton = new ImageButton();
t.label = "";
switch (functionCount.getItemAt(i))
{
    case "Val1":
        t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function():void{goToAgenda();});
    break;
    case "Val2":
        t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function():void{goToAdmin();});                                 
    break;
    case "Val3":
        t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function():void{goToMyStore();});                                   
        break;  
    case "Val4":        
        t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function():void{openBI();});
        break;  
}
  tile.addElement(t);
}
```

The `click` on the `ImageButton` call a Function that does somethings and than call the `navigator.pushView`
If I change the view, should I remove every EventListener from every button? 
Where is  the best place to do that?

If I have a view with 15000 compoenents, do I have to manually remove all the eventlistener added to each one when the view is removed???

**EDIT**

I mainly need to remove all event listener when a view is removed from stage so instead of doing it manually every time I thought an alternative and I create a simple class...

package utils
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

```
public class Evt
{
    public static var listaEvt:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    private var object:* = null;
    private var event:* = null;
    private var functio:* = null

    public function Evt(obj:*, evt:*, funct:Function)
    {
        this.object = obj;
        this.event = evt;
        this.functio = funct;
    }           

    public static function addEvt(obj:*, evt:*, funct:Function):void
    {
        var t:Evt = new Evt(obj, evt, funct);
        listaEvt.addItem(t);
    }

    public static function clear():void
    {
        var tmpArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        tmpArr.addAll(listaEvt);
        listaEvt = new ArrayCollection();
        for (var i:int = 0 ; i < tmpArr.length ; i++)
        {
            var t:Evt = tmpArr.getItemAt(i) as Evt;
            if (t.object != null && t.event != null && t.functio != null)
            {
                if (t.object.hasEventListener(t.event))
                    t.object.removeEventListener(t.event, t.functio);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my code anytime I do not need weak reference I call (also using anonymous function):

```
// t can be any component with a event associated...
var f:Function = function():void{navigator.pushView(FotoGallery,data);};
Evt.addEvt(t, MouseEvent.CLICK, f);
t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f);
```

Then when I enter a new view I do a simple `Evt.clear();` 
Is this approach effective? any advise to improve/change it?

Comment: You *do* realize there's `useWeakReferences`, right?

Comment: Yeah but I can't use that always... Let's assume I have a button that does something (like increment a counter), if I use weak reference, after click the listener is removed and the button did not work anymore...

Comment: The listener should stay active until the instance is garbage collected, unless you remove it manually.  Or if you use anonymous closures - if you don't retain a Function, it won't continue to exist after execution, either.

Comment: @Marcx Give a sample of code with these buttons. It's impossible what you just said.

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda No, it isn't - if he used weakReferences and an anonymous function.

Comment: I'm acutally use a lot of anonymous function...

Comment: @weltraumpirat Ah, right. So that is a big problem. If the code is filled with anonymous functions, I can't imagine fixing it without major refactoring. That is why it's a bad practice... but maybe someone will know the most painless way to fix that.

Comment: It's not a bad practice if you know what you're doing.  But anyway - assign the function to a private field of type Function, and the problem is solved. Not a big deal, especially not with a decent IDE.

Comment: @weltraumpirat can you explain better why should I assign the function to a private field? and if I use weak reference on a anonymous function doesn't it work?

Comment: `useWeakReference` is an odd little beast: if you don't know exactly how it works and what you're doing, do not use it and just clean up your event listeners manually.

Comment: By using anonymous function you created a closure. In basic terms a closure is a function that has lost scope. Anything that has lost scope can not be GCed without great difficulty. That is why weltraumpirat stated you should create a private field and assign it to it. In any case as you are finding out anonymous functions are a very bad coding practice and you should avoid them. My suggestion would be is to take a day or 2 and go back over your code and do away with the anon functions. In the end you will have a much better code base to work with.

Comment: And if You base app on Events , You should also think about extend EventDispatcher for function removeAllEvents(); and override addEventListener/removeEventListener that store registered events.

Comment: I updated my question adding a new class, please let me know if it's useful and if there are any advice or change to improve it...

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately larger applications may benefit from frameworks such as [Swiz Framework](http://swizframework.org/) or [Pure MVC](http://puremvc.org/), which can assist in:

- Inversion of Control / Dependency Injection
- Event handing and mediation
- A simple life cycle for asynchronous remote methods
- A framework that is decoupled from your application code

Swiz, for example, can use meta data tags to mediate events either catching events from the display list or injecting a dispatcher for events originating from non-UI sources.

```
[Dispatcher]
public var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;

[EventHandler( event="UserEvent.ADD_USER" )]
public function handleAddUserEvent( event:UserEvent ):void
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Otherwise, as mentioned, weak references in event listeners is an option:

```
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler, false, 0, true);
```

Views requiring isolated event handling can adapt to the intrinsic lifecycle of added and removed from stage.  Add listeners on `addedToStage` when the display object is ready to handle signals from the display list, and dispose listeners on `removedFromStage` when the display object no longer requires event handling.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MyClass extends Sprite
    {
        public function MyClass()
        {
            super();

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStageHandler);

            /* add event listeners here */
        }

        protected function removedFromStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStageHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

            /* remove event listeners here */
        }

        protected function dispose():void
        {
            /* any remaining cleanup */
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE/Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE. When object is removed from stage it's still referenced because of "addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler)" in removedFromStageHandler. Do I miss something? Maybe dispose() is a good place to remove listener for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE/Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE whichever is active at the moment.